# Iterate through List of Object and verify attributes (int) are following each others (ex : (1,2,3,4), (3,4,5,6) but not (1,2,5) or (3,4,5,7))

Tags: java, list, attributes, int, compare

I'm working on a board game in Java and I want to verify that the letters are "touching" each others when placed on the board.

I'm using a `List<Letter>`. When letters are placed, I'm verifying that its aligned either vertically or horizontally (using the `(x,y)` positions of the letters). I've also made 2 custom `Comparators` for my `Letter` class so after that I can sort the `List<Letter>` under the x or y position (depending if the word is aligned vertically or horizontally).

Now in order to verify the letters are "touching" each others, I have to verify that the x's (or the y's depending how it's aligned) are something like : `1,2,3,4` and not `1,2,3,5` for instance (That would mean there is a "space" between letter 3 and 4).

I have to iterate through my `List<Letter>` but I don't know exactly which test I have to do inside the foreach. I have to compare the `x` of the first object with the `x` of the next object and it has to be x's position +1.

I hope it's clear, here are some snippets of my code and the classes involved so you can understand a bit the structure. English is not my first langage so feel free to ask if you need any precisions. Thanks in advance for your help!

*As I'm not posting a lot on stackoverflow I tried to do my best for the text formatting here on the message, hope it's readable for you guys!*

```java
public class Letter {
int x,y;

public int getX() {
//...
}
public int getY() {
//...
}

public static Comparator<Letter> COMPARE_BY_X = (Letter a, Letter b) -> {
// ...
}

public static Comparator<Letter> COMPARE_BY_Y = (Letter a, Letter b) -> {
// ...
}

public int hashCode() {
//...
}
public boolean equals() {
//...
}

}


public class VerifyWord(List<Letter> word) {

private List<Letter> word;
//...


// list is sorted
for (Letter t : word) {
// what should I put there????
}


//...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a for each loop, because then you will only be able to access one of the `Letter` elements at a time. Iterate over the indices and check whether the x-coordinate of the next element is one greater than the x-coordinate of the current element. For instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (word.get(i+1).getX() != (word.get(i).getX() + 1)) {
        // error
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something very similar but at some point I ended with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because of the `word.get(i+1)` at the last iteration of the `for` loop

Comment: @raphh Make sure that your loop condition is `i < word.size() - 1` or `i <= word.size() - 2` instead of `i < word.size()`. Since the loop is checking the next `Letter`, we don't want to go to the end of the loop; we want to stop at the second to last element.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, my reflexion about that was "if I go until `word.size()-1`i'll miss a letter", but as you explained, that doesn't matter since it's the spacing between the letters that I'm looking at. So when I'm at the second to last letter I can verify the spacing between that letter and the last one.

Answer (score 1):

When I was relatively new to programming, a more experienced guy explained the "picket fence problem" to me: between each pair of adjoining pickets there is a gap. If you number the pickets from 1 to n, the gaps may be numbered from 1 to n-1 *or* from 2 to n.

So, if the `List<Letter> letters` is the pickets they are numbered from 0 to letters.size()-1. And the gaps - the distances between to adjoining letters - are numbered from 0 to letters.size()-2.

```
for( int iLetter = 0; iLetter < letters.size() - 1; iLetter++ ){
    int gap = distance(letters.get(iLetter+1) - letters.get(iLetter));
    if( gap != 1 ) ...
}
```

If you prefer, you can write the loop as

```
for( int iLetter = 0; iLetter <= letters.size() - 2; iLetter++ ){
```

Comment: Oh I see. It's sort of a different way to approach the problem but nevertherless really interesting. It might be useful to keep that in mind in the future. Thank you for your input.